# Piping line-by-line

Tags: shell, scripting, pipe, buffer

I have a script that "listens" to `amixer` events (volume change and mute), piping the volume and mute status to [`xob`](https://github.com/florentc/xob). It works great, but the (ab)use of `stdbuf -oL <command>` looks wrong to me, and I was wondering if there was any other way to do what I wanted. I think I'm looking for a way to make every command in a script line-buffered.

Portable answers are appreciated, though this script isn't all that portable.

I'm new to shell scripting, so other improvements to the script are extra appreciated!

Here is the script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Wait for amixer to become available
until [ "$(amixer)" ]; do sleep 0.1; done

get_volume () {
    OUT=$(amixer sget Master)
    VOLUME=$(echo $OUT | awk -F"[][]" '/Left:/ { print $2 }' | tr -d '%')
    STATE=$(echo $OUT | awk -F"[][]" '/Left:/ { print $4 }')

    [ "$STATE" = "off" ] && VOLUME="$VOLUME!"

    echo $VOLUME
}

stdbuf -oL amixer events \
    | stdbuf -oL grep -E "event value: numid=(3|4)" \
    | stdbuf -oL tail -n +2 \
    | while read REPLY; do get_volume; done \
    | xob
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `grep` (as found on systems that have `amixer`) does have a `--line-buffered` option. To tell it to buffer its output linewise.

You can easily do the `tail -n+2` and filtering in the shell as well, so:

```
get_volume() {
  amixer sget Master |
    awk -F'[][]' '/Left:/ {print 0+$2 ($4 == "off" ? "!" : "")}'
}

skip=1
stdbuf -oL amixer events |
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    case ${line%%,*} in
      ('event value: numid='[34])
        if [ "$skip" -eq 0 ]; then
          get_volume
        else
          skip=$(( skip - 1 ))
        fi
    esac
  done | xob
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I suppose I was overzealous with the pipes.